# Cannot disable keyboard bindings

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 I've discovered some new annoying key binding that I wasn't not able to disable.

Examples:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> causes the X server to crash and lock all input.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> switches input language to a matching by the first letter (don't ask...)
- Setting `DontVTSwitch` to true didn't help disabling kbd>Ctrl+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>

How can I disable / remap these key bindings?

Comment: Can't you do it from _Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard_ ?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I would not have asked if I could. DontVTSwitch flag worked in previous version, both with X and Wayland.